# GET a resource filtering by a composite key as query parameter?

Tags: rest, restful-url

I'm thinking the best way to create an endpoint that one of the filters be a composite key.

Per example, we have a rest service to search for orders:

```
/orders/
```

We can filter the orders by start and final date:

```
/orders?dt-start=2017-05-11T17:12Z&dt-final=2017-05-11T17:12Z
```

Until here, so far so good. But I would like to filter the orders by customer. The customer is identified by his **type** of document and **number** of this document.

So, something like this could be possible:

```
/orders?type=ID&number=123456789
```

But the type and number are query parameters that only work **together**, it's a composite key. But using query parameter - like the last example -  seems that the API user can do too:

```
/orders?number=123456789
/orders?type=ID
```

But not makes sense. Yes, I could return an error in response (bad request) if only one of these parameters were passed, but this is not natural for who are reading the API endpoint.

Another strategy is combine type and number in the same parameter, but I never see this in any API.

```
/orders?document=ID-12345678
```

It's odd to me too. I prefer to use separated parameters instead of this.

So, there are a way to use query parameter and solve this problem in a more "elegant" way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make up a composite key, instead conditionally require the two params. This ins't bad and IMO is much cleaner than creating a composite key which isn't represented by the data (or resource).

I've done this before, so to help illustrate I'll point you to it. [This](https://www.surfwatchlabs.com/tech-docs/api#js-get-cyberfacts) resource is to query for CyberFacts. The query is bound by a date range. To get data, you can do one of two things.

1. You can say `?today=true`, and get the data for today (equivalent to saying `?startDate=2017-05-13&endDate=2017-05-13`)
2. You can use the `startDate` and `endDate` query parameters, however if you use one and not the other (eg `?startDate=2017-05-13`) you will receive a `400 Bad Request` status response on the query and a error message in the response body.

So in this case I've done a few things to make this work

1. Make a higher priority parameter (`today` overrides `startDate` and `endDate`)
2. Document the valid behaviors
3. Provide appropriate error responses

For you only **#2** and **#3** would be needed, I think. Not knowing all of your use cases, I would suggest using `/orders?type=ID&number=123456789` and document that `number` is a require query param when `type=ID`, and also include the appropriate error (eg: "You queried for an Order by Type 'ID', however you did not provide a 'number' query parameter")

Answer (score 0):

How about providing a default value for `type`, (such as 'ID') as a fallback if the `type` parameter is absent (I'd probably go for the most common/used document type depending on your situation).

While for the `number` parameter I would enforce it, i.e. by specifying that it is a *required* parameter (somewhere in the docs?). If absent, return a bad request.